# What is the meaning of "plus" in "150,000 plus"?

Tags: meaning

For example:

> Now the 150,000 plus small coffee shops here may need to concoct something else strong to hold their ground.

Comment: Seems like a question for https://ell.stackexchange.com/ imho though really

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standard way to read "30+"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451912/is-there-a-standard-way-to-read-30) 1006a's answer explains the '30-plus' / '150,000 plus' usage: the range of intended values (is the cited number itself a possibility? for instance). n+ means a value x ∈ N: n ≤ x ≤ (around 1·1n - 1·3n) (though some might say that n itself is not included).

Comment: Why people linking the same question?

Comment: @1409  That's because I overran the 5 minutes allowed to adapt/expand a comment after the set duplicate CV comment appeared. I had to repost the comment, and the next CV-er has their identical set comment (minus the additional, of course) posted. Too long to find ∈, ≤, and ·, and then decide on an appropriate upper bound (30+ wouldn't usually be used for say 50. But 'At 16+, you have the right to give consent to medical, dental and surgical treatment' obviously includes the lower bound (from 16th birthday) and has no implied upper bound.)

Answer (score 0):

"Plus" means "or more" here.

From [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=plus)

> or more (but not less).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oxford Languages has 'at least that specified'. The usage is ill-defined.

Comment: I changed it to a proper fit

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanation and please be patient with repeated questions! Didn't know the meaning and neither how to seach for it! Best regards!